# .NET IComparable: how to implement

Tags: c#, .net

I have a collection of objects I need to order but not sure how.

There is a string property called, say Prop1, that I want to sort by. And I want to sort based on a List of strings which contain all possible values of Prop1.

```
List<string> precedence = new List<string>() { "firstPrecedence", "secondPrecedence" ....
```

How would I implement my CompareTo(object obj) method?

I'm trying with this but don't really know what i'm doing!

```
    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        List<string> precedence = new List<string>() { "firstPrecedence", "secondPrecedence", "thirdPrecedence" };

        Filter filterOther = obj as Filter;

        foreach (var item in precedence)
        {
            return String.Compare(filterOther.FilterValue, item);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: If you are implementing `IComparable`, you should be comparing values of `this` to values of `obj` - but in your example it is not clear to me what (if any) values come from the current object...? or what the rules are for sorting... can you please clarify with an example of inputs and outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if your precedence list is known at compile time and you can use it, then you can compare the ***indexes*** of the values you are sorting:

```
private static List<string> Precedence = new List<string>() { "item1", "item2", "item3" }; // etc

public int CompareTo(object obj)
{
    Filter item = obj as Filter; // Assume not null.   
    int otherIndex = Precedence.IndexOf(item.FilterValue);
    int thisIndex = Precedence.IndexOf(this.FilterValue); // Assume 'this' is a Filter

    // This may need to be otherIndex.CompareTo(thisIndex) depending on the direction of sort you want.
    return thisIndex.CompareTo(otherIndex);
}
```

If the `FilterValue` value is not in the list, `IndexOf` will return -1, which will still work in the sorting implementation here, but may sort at the top or bottom of the list... I can never remember which!

Note that the `CompareTo` method returns either 0, something less than 0, or something greater than 0.  Usually, -1, 0, and 1.

Also, there is a generic `IComparable<>` which will allow you to achieve this in a more strongly-typed way:

```
public class Filter : IComparable<Filter>
{

}
```

And I'm sure some clever person will give you a solution in LINQ...

Answer (score 1):

try this (assuming you have a `List<Filter>` )

```
filterObjectList.Sort((f1,f2) => precedence.IndexOf(f1.FilterValue).CompareTo(precedence.IndexOf(f2.FilterValue));
```

Comment: Well, considerably more concise than my attempt :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ:

```
precedence.SelectMany(p => objs.Where(o => o.Prop1 == p));
```

OR

```
objs.Select(s => new { Index = precedence.IndexOf(s.Prop1), Obj = s })
                .OrderBy(a => a.Index).Select(a => a.Obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class of your object that you want to sort:

```
public class MySortableObject: IComparable {

    private string str;

    public MySortableObject(string _str) {
        this.str = _str;
    }

    int IComparable.CompareTo(object obj) {
        MySortableObject comparedObj = (MySortableObject) obj;

        // Implement here the code that will compare the current object (this) and the compared object (comparedObj)
        // It must return -1 if this instance precedes comparedObj in the sort order
        // It must return 1 if this instance follows comparedObj in the sort order
        // It must return 0 if this instance occurs in the same position in the sort order as comparedObj

        // Use for example String.CompareTo() method to implement this, or your own code (with if(), switch()... whatever you need)
    }
}
```